# CSS hover function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have some JS written that when a table row is clicked on it removes the CSS of that ID.

On my laptop browser the class is not removed when the click occurs but when the cursor is moved off the element in this case the TR.

I found out the problem causing this was the following CSS code as it's the same hover colour as the highlight to aid the user select the correct row:

```
tr:hover td{ background-color:#003f7f; color:#ffffff;}
```

On my iPhone for example the CSS class is not removed until the page refreshes as there is no cursor.

Is there anyway to implement a hover function in the desktop browser and not on a mobile device as they "hover" on the mobile seems to be selected always when the page is touched?

Comment: Please share your code through jsfiddle or codepen.

Comment: Hover is a bad idea for any mobile device since as you have observed - hover doesn't really exist for a touch screen. You could consider using a click or something more explicit.

Comment: there is a jquery plugin called [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) you can use for mobile devices

Comment: apologies for that getting used to all this but here's the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/crookesa/8PWx9/

Answer (score 0):

You can remove this CSS for your iphone using @media queries.

Please go through the below links where you can get basic Idea to apply media queries in your CSS file and on the bases of device width, different devices you can override CSS accordingly.

http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-with-css3-media-queries

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/media-queries.html

HTH

Comment: Please always include some useful code directly in your answer. External sites may be changed or deleted at any time, so link-only answers are frowned upon on StackOverflow.